# cython and numpy: 'cfunc.to_py:65:25: 'ndarray' is not a type identifier'

Tags: numpy, cython

I have a cdef function which takes two numpy.ndarrays as argument (1). It gives me the an 'cfunc.to_py:65:25: 'ndarray' is not a type identifier' error. 
when I replace the cdef with a def (python) function (2) or a cpdef (3), the error disappears. Is this a bug? How can I solve this? code is below.

(1) `cdef float F(np.ndarray xx, np.ndarray y_non_labor, float wage, float gamma, float one_by_gamma, float l, float one_minus_l, int lenx):`

(2) `def F(np.ndarray xx, np.ndarray y_non_labor, float wage, float gamma, float one_by_gamma, float l, float one_minus_l, int lenx):`

(3) `cpdef float F(np.ndarray xx, np.ndarray y_non_labor, float wage, float gamma, float one_by_gamma, float l, float one_minus_l, int lenx):`

```
# cython: profile=True
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from scipy.optimize import minimize
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np


# due to instabilities associated with "constraint optimization" with bounds
# we will transform the problem so that that it becomes an unconstraint optimization problem without bounds

def transform(x):
    x1 = x * x / (1 + x * x)
    s =  1 - sum(x1)
    return x1, s

# on the next cython update try cdef float F(..)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef float F(np.ndarray xx, np.ndarray y_non_labor, float wage, float gamma, float one_by_gamma, float l, float one_minus_l, int lenx):
    cdef float s
    cdef float *z_non_labor = <float *>malloc(lenx * sizeof(float))
    cdef float z_labor
    cdef float labor
    cdef float value
    cdef float summation
    cdef float non_labor
    cdef float x
    cdef float ynl

    for i from 0 <= i < lenx:
        x = xx[i]
        z_non_labor[i] = x * x / (1 + x * x)

    s = 0
    for i from 0 <= i < lenx:
        s += z_non_labor[i]

    z_labor = 1 - s

    summation = 0
    for i from 0 <= i < lenx:
        ynl = y_non_labor[i]
        summation += (z_non_labor[i] / ynl) ** gamma

    non_labor = summation ** one_by_gamma
    labor = z_labor / wage
    # labor and non-labor inputs together
    value = (labor ** l) * (non_labor ** one_minus_l)
    return - value

def optimization(np.ndarray seed_weights,
                 np.ndarray input_prices,
                 float wage,
                 float gamma,
                 float one_by_gamma,
                 float l,
                 float one_minus_l):

    cdef int lenx

    lenx = len(seed_weights)

    args=(input_prices,
          wage,
          gamma,
          one_by_gamma,
          l,
          one_minus_l,
          lenx)

    return minimize(F, seed_weights, args=args, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it's a fairly obscure bug. Explanation follows. Work-round is at the end of the answer.

On Cython 0.21 I get a different error

```
filename.pyx:73:21: Cannot convert 'float (ndarray, ndarray, float,
float, float, float, float, int)' to Python object.
```

This makes sense to me because `minimise` takes a callable Python object as its first answer, while `cdef` generates a C function only. [`cpdef` generates both and calls the C function where it can]

On Cython 0.22 and 0.23 I get the error you describe. The full error is

```
@cname("__Pyx_CFunc_float____ndarray____ndarray____float____float____float____float____float____int___to_py")
cdef object __Pyx_CFunc_float____ndarray____ndarray____float____float____float____float____float____int___to_py(float (*f)(ndarray, ndarray, float, float, float, float, float, int) except *):
    def wrap(ndarray xx, ndarray y_non_labor, float wage, float gamma, float one_by_gamma, float l, float one_minus_l, int lenx):
                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cfunc.to_py:30:25: 'ndarray' is not a type identifier
```

You'll note that this is for a function `wrap` which you don't define. `wrap` seems to be generated only because you're calling `minimize`, and it realises you need a Python object here, so helpfully makes a `def` function for you (if you comment out the call to `minimize` the error goes away). This appears to be an enhancement that was made around Cython 0.22.

Unfortunately, the code for wrap uses `ndarray` rather than `np.ndarray` as you've defined it (this has to be a bug!). **The workround is to add the following line**

```
from numpy cimport ndarray
```

(which makes `ndarray` on its own a valid type).

However, given `minimize` calls it through the Python-compatible wrapper by necessity, you might as well just use `cpdef` (which is also called through a Python-compatible wrapper, but one generated in a different way without the bug). There's pretty much no disadvantage to using `cpdef` - the function will still get called quickly as a pure C function where possible and work fine from Python too (albeit slightly slower).